# java android WebView progress dialog problem

Tags: java, webview, android-webview, progress-bar

The progress bar is disabled when I add the code in the second part I added to activate search and mail connections in the Webview application.

```
    webViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
    wprogressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    wprogressDialog.setMessage("yapayreklam.com Loading..");
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    webView.getSettings().getAllowFileAccess();
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.getSettings().getAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs();
```

The progress dialog does not work when I add this section below.

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                return false;
            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity( intent );
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, added progress dialog closing.

```
if(wprogressDialog.isShowing()){
            wprogressDialog.dismiss();
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                        return false;
                    }


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity( intent );
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```